# second shm_open() fails with ENOENT

Tags: linux

```
mode_t mode = S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO;
shm_fd = shm_open("/ipc_shm", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, mode);
```

This works, returns 4 for shm_fd. The same process then calls a library function that also calls

```
fd = shm_open("/ipc_shm", O_RDWR, 0);
```

This one fails with errno set to 2, i.e. ENOENT (No such file or directory). There is no shm_unlink call in the middle. Any idea why the second call is failing. Appreciate your help.

Comment: The only way I can reproduce this is if indeed the shared memory is unlinked one way or another.  If it's not done from that program, it's done by another one.

Answer (score 1):

my test.c:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>        /* For mode constants */
#include <fcntl.h>           /* For O_* constants */

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        mode_t mode = S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO;
        int shm_fd = shm_open("/ipc_shm", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, mode);
        int fd = shm_open("/ipc_shm", O_RDWR, 0);

        return 0;
}
```

compiled with `gcc test.c -Wall -lrt` works as expected:

```
$strace ./a.out 
....  
statfs("/dev/shm/", {f_type=0x1021994, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=22290, f_bfree=22290, f_bavail=22290, f_files=55725, f_ffree=55723, f_fsid={0, 0}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096}) = 0
futex(0xb6f5d1c0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
open("/dev/shm/ipc_shm", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC, 0777) = 3
fcntl64(3, F_GETFD)                     = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
open("/dev/shm/ipc_shm", O_RDWR|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
exit_group(0)
```

Please run strace on your application, and search for all occurrences of ipc, and maybe chroot(). Maybe something unlinks the file?